# Download url images in CSV file and rename the images with data from other cells in the file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

First I want apologize for my question. I am very new to programming; I am just trying to learn whenever I get a chance. I have a task at work that I have not been able to resolve. 
I have a csv file with three columns:
VendorID - Invoice# -URL

I have thousands of images that I need to download from these urls. Once the image is downloaded it needs to be saved with the following naming convention:

"vendorID_Invoice#"

For example:

VendorID    Invoice#    URL
ABD           1234      www.example.com/”imagepath”
Image name = ABD_1234

I was able to create the script to download the images, but I can't figure out how to do the renaming part. I ended up creating two files: One with just the URLs and another one with the VendorID and the Invoice#. I apologize for the messy code below:

**Script to download the images:**

import urllib.request

```
import os

print(os.getcwd())
new_path = os.chdir('DirectoryPath')
print(os.getcwd())

filename = "imagescopy"

# open file to read
with open("{0}.csv".format(filename), 'r') as csvfile:
    # iterate on all lines
    fo = open("avidlogcopy.csv", "w")
    i = 0
    for line in csvfile:
        splitted_line = line.split(',')
        # check if we have an image URL
        if splitted_line[0] != '' and splitted_line[0] != "\n":
            token = splitted_line[0].rsplit('/', 1)[-1] #I was trying to name the images with the last item in the URL
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[0], token[:-1] + ".PDF")
            print(token + "Image saved for {0}".format("splitted_line[0]"))
            i = i +1
            fo.write(token)
        else:
            result_negative = print ("No result 
            for{0}".format("splitted_line[0]"))
            fo.write(result_negative + '\n')
    fo.close()
```

**Script to Name the files**

```
import csv
with open('MRIdatadump.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as g:
        writer = csv.writer(g)
        for row in reader:
            new_row = ['_'.join([row[0], row[1]])] + row[2:]
            new_name = new_row[0]
            print(new_name)
            writer.writerow(new_row)
```

I hope that you can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't have access to your CSV-file, I just have to assume that you did the parsing part correct. According to the info and code you provided, `splitted_line = line.split(',')` should be an array with three objects:

```
splitted_line[0] # Contains Vendor ID
splitted_line[1] # Contains Invoice number
splitted_line[2] # Contains URL
```

In the [`urrlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) docs, you can see that you can give the desired local file name as the second argument to `urllib.request.urlretrieve`, as you have attempted.

I suggest the following: Instead of doing this

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[0], token[:-1] + ".PDF")
```

We create our filename and use that like so

```
vendorID = splitted_line[0]
invoiceNr= splitted_line[1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(splitted_line[0], "{}_{}".format(vendorID,invoiceNR))
```

Now, since you haven't provided runnable code, there is no way for me of checking if this works. In the future I urge you to make a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you; the script is working now. The only change that I had to make was to the columns order in the CSV file. I had to ensure that the URL was in column[0], otherwise, the script could not find the URL (it was changing the URL with just numbers).  Though, after I made the sript started to work well.

Comment: Great! Since you presented a column order in the question, I believe that it should be in the same order.